# Como implementar o método verifyDeveloperPayload?

Tags: android, android-billing

Alguém sabe como faço para implementar essa função, quando se trabalha com Google Billing?

Vi que um token deve ser gerado para verificação de licença e evitar fraudes.

Mas alguém sabe como implementar, por que implementar e os riscos que se corre, caso não seja implementado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que aqui está muito bem explicado :)

http://codigo-google.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/implementar-in-app-billing-em-android.html

Answer (score 1):

O DeveloperPayload é apenas mais uma maneira de deixar o processo todo de compra mais seguro.
Caso não seja implementado, você está deixando de fazer mais uma verificação pra saber se a requisição é verdadeira. Estaria deixando um usuário (usando hack?) comprar vários items do seu app sem te pagar, por exemplo.

---

### Como funciona?

Ao iniciar o processo de compra dentro do app, você cria um payload, que deve ser diferente para cada usuário, mas não diferente para cada aparelho (pois se um usuário fizer uma compra em um aparelho, ele tem que conseguir recuperar essa compra em outro aparelho). Usar uma string aleatória também não é legal, pelo mesmo motivo da mudança de aparelho.

O método verifyDeveloperPayload() é usado para verificar se o payload que veio da requisição é o mesmo que você usou para iniciar a requisição.

O recomendado é usar um servidor próprio para armazenar essas informações, assim independente da versão do app, ou do aparelho utilizado, é possível verificar se o payload está correto.

---

Se quiser ler mais sobre isso:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#payload

Comment: Até aí tudo bem, mas no caso de eu não querer (ou não poder) ter um servidor próprio, existe alguma forma de eu fazer essa verificação? Eu vi aqui que talvez eu possa gerar a chave no momento da requisição e quando houver um retorno, caso de compra, eu verifico se foi o mesmo gerado na requisição. As vezes, assim possa funcionar...